# Browser simplified

Tags: windows, google-chrome, offline

I have a customer (a very old person) who wants an application that *"has nothing to do with the interwebz"*. So what I'm going to do is an offline web application; but my problem now is the browser. Is there a way to simplify chrome or another browser just like I show in the image? Without bars nor buttons nor anything.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an application shortcut in Chrome:

1. Open the url of your website
2. Open the Wrench menu
3. Create application shortcut

This will open Chrome without any address bar or toolbars.